# I am not able to click on button in protractor

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor

Html code

```
 <button type="button" ng-click="submitPosition($event, true);navigate($event,'/#/project')" class="btn  btn-main" name="submit">CREATE POSITION AND AUTOSOURCE</button>
```

My code.

Two buttons have same class name so am using filter.

```
element.all(by.css('button.btn.btn-main')).filter(function(button,index){
            return index == 1;
            }).each(function(button){
            button.click();
            });
```

I am getting this error

```
UnknownError: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (1049, 162). Other element would receive the click: <ul class="modal-breadcrumb list-unstyled block">...</ul>
  (Session info: chrome=43.0.2357.132)
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the error, it looks like you've got a modal blocking your click. Not seeing the rest of the code, it's hard to say, but you'll need to get around that. That said, the overall issue could be your locator strategy. Using `filter` here is overboard, and perhaps trying to clicking the wrong thing?

I would try:

```
element(by.cssContainingText('button.btn.btn-main', 'CREATE POSITION AND AUTOSOURCE'));
```

or

```
$$('button.btn.btn-main').get(1); // assuming index 1 is the button you're after
```

or if it's the only submit:

```
$('button[name="submit"]');
```

Comment: Hi @Brine : i have as similar problem the click function is executed but there is no effect for that no click effect no redirection even if i put a browser.sleep() or actions after that all of them failed because the test stop here !Do you have an idea about that ?

Comment: @Emma, post a new question, include the code, and we'll have a look

Answer (score 0):

This may result due to the following reason ,

The button you want to click on is at the bottom of the page(not visible on the page).
you have to scroll down a bit to expose the button in our browser.Then you can click on it.

You can use mouseMove() to scroll to element first:

```
browser.actions().mouseMove(btnSave).click();
```

or

use browser.executeScript() function  to do the scrolling:

```
 browser.executeScript('window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);');
```

you should give a specific id to your button and use the by id to click

```
element(by.id('buttonId')).click();
```

Comment: It's complaining about a modal being in the way... if it was off screen, it would error with element not found.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the modal eventually goes away? or if you have to click on something else for the modal to go away but I've found using the [expected conditions](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/expectedConditions.js) to be helpful

```
var button      = element.all(by.css('button.btn.btn-main')).first();
var IsClickable = EC.elementToBeClickable(button);

browser.wait(IsClickable, 5000, "Failed to click the button").then(function() {
    button.click();
});
```